# How can I tell if a proxy is SOCKS or HTTP using a command in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, proxy, http, socks

Is there a simple command to run in a Linux terminal *to tell if a proxy is SOCKS or HTTP*?

Answer (score 3):

You could check which of the relevant ports is open (e.g. using telnet). Socks usually uses port 1080, HTTP usually uses 80, 443, 8443 or 8080.

Answer (score 3):

Other then just trying if it's SOCKS or HTTP, no , you can't.

To test if it's a http proxy:

```
set http_proxy = http://1.0.0.1:8080 
wget --proxy=on http://www.google.com/
```

This will download the html root of google, and if it has correct content, you know it was a http proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following shell command with `curl` to check:

```
ip=127.0.0.1
port=8080
(timeout 2 curl -x socks5://$ip:$port -qs -o/dev/null http://example.com/ && printf "socks5\t$ip\t$port\n") \
|| (timeout 2 curl -x socks4://$ip:$port -qs -o/dev/null http://example.com/ && printf "socks4\t$ip\t$port\n") \
|| (timeout 2 curl -x http://$ip:$port -qs -o/dev/null http://example.com/ && printf "http\t$ip\t$port\n")
```

For the full script, check [`check_proxies.sh` file](https://github.com/kenorb/proxy_list/blob/master/check_proxies.sh).

Answer (score 0):

On my SLES11 VM, I run `socklist` and `grep` for the port:

> `dev-s11:~ # socklist | grep 22
>
>   tcp      22      21112       0   4345    3  sshd
>
>   tcp      22   10473174       0  32616    3  sshd`

That tells me whether it's managed by ssh or not. If you are using default ports, http will be 80 and ssh 22. That will get you started - ask more Qs if you need more specifics.